# Como listar o maior salário dentre todas as funções dos funcionários?

Tags: sql

Gente, quero saber como faço para listar apenas a função que possui o maior salário e não os maiores salários de todas as funções, alguém me dá uma luz?
Segue como estou fazendo:

```
select max(Salario) from Funcionarios group by Funcao;
```

Também fiz assim:

```
select max(Salario) from Funcionarios;
```

E é dessa última forma que eu quero. Quero exibir o maior salário dentre todas as funções e também o nome dessa função que possui o maior salário, porém não sei como fazer.

Comment: Se houver mais de uma função com o mesmo salário, como será tratado? É para exibir todos?

Comment: Não tinha pensado nessa possibilidade. No exemplo que eu fiz, coloquei salários diferentes.

Comment: Exato, resposta do Higor resolve teu problema porém poderá ocorrer essa situação.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SELECT funcao from Funcionarios WHERE salario = (select max(salario) from Funcionarios);`

provavelmente tem uma solução melhor que essa, mas no momento nao consigo pensar em alguma :D

Comment: Vou testar =) Valeu.

Comment: 'select Funcao, Salario from Funcionarios where salario = (select max(Salario) from Funcionarios);' fiz uma pequena alteração, valeu!